# How to diagnose "Entering an unknown directory"

Tags: makefile, qnx

I'm getting up to speed on this QNX project with a bunch of make files I'm still getting the gist of coming from a Visual Studio background. The build output from momentics leaves much to be desired but there's one particular error that I wish there were more feedback for.

```
make: Entering an unknown directory
make: Leaving an unknown directory
make: *** P:\Sources_xxx\xxxx\ProjectX\x86\o: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [ProjectX] Error 2
```

We're porting code that built in VC++ so I can't just back up to the last change which introduced this error since it's all coming at once. I suppose there's something wrong with the make file but don't have the debugging skills in QNX `make` to get the `make` output to tell me what directory it's struggling with. Is the directory that's being said to be unknown the same as the ProjectX\x86\o??

Comment: Well, first I haven't looked at QNX in a long time but last time I did it was a UNIX-ish system, so it would not use pathnames like `P:\foo\bar`, it would use UNIX paths like `/p/foo/bar` or whatever.  Are you using some special filesystem on QNX which is NTFS-like?  That message from GNU make says that it was not able to find the working directory; you should have gotten an error before the first line you show about why the directory lookup failed.

Comment: The build output gets scrambled and hard to trace from all the parallel builds writing to the console. What wound up occurring is that I didn't realize I needed to commit to source control the intermediate directories: `x86\o`. Coming from that VisualStudio background similar directories get generated on the fly and aren't intended for commit to source control. I'll write up an answer on this in a bit. The terminology of _unknown_ directory was pretty unfamiliar and ambiguous for me, something along the lines of directory not found is closer to home.

Comment: @MadScientist, on the pathstyle, we're actually building QNX stuff and running momentics off Windows boxes and moving the binaries over to the QNX boxes to run.

Answer (score 2):

So it does look like the error message pertains to the folder in question `P:\Sources_xxx\xxxx\ProjectX\x86\o`, this is apparently the unknown directory, which is basically a directory that does not exist on the file system. From our build setup we were expected to commit to source control the output folders that are generated according to the `Build Variants` specified in the project settings, which in our case were X86.

This wasn't clear to us who are new on the team working with QNX since coming from Visual Studio such intermediate folders get automatically created and are not expected to be checked into source control. The thing that obscured this too is that the folder existed on my developer system when I created the new QNX project, but not being in source control was not found on the Build Server which is where the error was seen.